# How to import and save data from csv in web2py database table?

Tags: sqlite, csv, web2py

I used SQlite database. 
I wrote code like this

```
Module:
db.py
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite') 
db.define_table('data3')
db.data3.import_from_csv_file(open('mypath/test.csv'),'r')
Controller:
def website_list():
       return dict(websites = db().select(db.data4.ALL))
View:
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>List Of Websites</h2>
<table class="flakes-table" style="width:100% ;">
        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="id" >ID</a></td>
                          <td class="link" >Link</td>
                        </tr>
        </thead>
        {{for web in websites:}}
        <tbody class="list">
            <tr>
                <td >{{=web.id}}</td>

                <td >{{=web.Link}</td>
            </tr>{{pass}}
        </tbody>
</table>
```

But it is showing error as

"type 'exceptions.AttributeError'"

Also error has this line
Function argument list
(self=, key='data3')

I think some thing is wrong in reading csv file. My csv file has following data

"Link_Title","Link"

"Apple's Ad Blockers Rile Publishers","somelink"

"Uber Valued at More Than $50 Billion","somelink"

"England to Roll Out Tailored Billboards","somelink"

Can anyone help in this..?

Comment: `db.define_table('data3')` Your table doesn't have any columns! Not sure about  it!

Comment: You are importing data in table `data3`, but you are retrieving it from table `data4`

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks!!! I defined a table with fields and then tried to import data it works.

Comment: Also take `<tbody class="list">` outside for loop

Comment: As Gaurav suggests I added Fields and then Import csv.
     
db.define_table('data7',
               Field('Title',requires =IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
               Field('Link',requires =IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
     db.data7.import_from_csv_file(open('mypath/test.csv'),'r')
It works. 

But having new problem 

Each time I refresh my webpage It shows multiple records as below 

1, Link1

2, Link2

3, Link1

4  Link2 
I am getting repeated rows. 
Any solution ..?

Comment: You run the import on every view. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118947/repetition-of-data-for-import-from-csv-file-in-web2py-for-sqlite-database-tabl) for more details