# Repetition of data for import_from_csv_file() in web2py for sqlite database table

Tags: sqlite, csv, web2py

I want to load data from csv file into SQlite database. My code is :

```
Model:
db.define_table('data_table',
           Field('Title',requires =IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
           Field('Link',requires =IS_NOT_EMPTY()))

db.data_table.import_from_csv_file(open('mycsv'),'rb')
Controller:
def index():
    query=((db.data_table.id))
    fields = (db.data_table.id, db.data_table.Title, db.data_table.Link)
    headers = {'data_table.id': 'ID',
            'db.data_table.Title': 'Title',
            'db.data_table.Link': 'Link',
            }
    default_sort_order=[db.data_table.id]
    form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, fields=fields, headers=headers,orderby=default_sort_order,
    create=False, deletable=False, editable=False, maxtextlength=64, paginate=10)
    return dict(form=form)
```

Here when I load this form in index.html I am getting repeated rows in Gridview.

e.g. If I have 5 rows in csv file then very first time it will show 5 records  but when I refresh the index.html then each time it adds on those 5 records.

On 1st refresh it gives me 45 records. On 2nd refresh it gives 100 records. In this way it goes on increasing.

My doubt is where should I write this line

```
db.data_table.import_from_csv_file(open('mycsv'),'rb')
```

In Model or Controller or View

Please help me in this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't write it in model or controller. Import data through external script. so that `db.data_table.import_from_csv_file(open('mycsv'),'rb')` is not executed multiple times and there will be no repetition. Can you tell more about what you want to do so that i can give right answer!

Comment: @Gaurav. Thanks!!! I have a csv file which has 1000 rows. I want to display all the rows in html page. So that user can see it and If necessary he can modify it.

Comment: csv file is not going to change? Whether csv file is taken as user input?  You can also do import from web2py shell ( `python web2py.py -S aplication_name -M`). Run `db.data_table.import_from_csv_file(open('mycsv'),'rb')`  `db.commit()`

Comment: Your problem is solved or still facing issues?

Comment: @Gaurav Hi , I can run above command but I am not able to see the database when I run web2py server. : ( can't guess any solution!! Any way Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still having problem with this...!!!

Comment: can you do one thing if you don't mind sharing your all code? Create .w2p file of your application and share it, also share csv file you want to import! To create .w2p file of your application, go to web2py administrative interface and  in installed applications, you will see 'pack all' option. In my case - http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/default/site

Comment: In case you do want to repeatedly import the CSV (let's say for testing or educational purposes) create a new database conection like `empty_db = DAL('sqlite:memory:')` as it is fresh with each request.